# http to https and non-www. to www. redirect HSTS header htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

1. I have a new website with an empty `.htaccess` file. I want to do the following:

   - redirect http to https
   - redirect non-`www.` to `www.`

I do not want to redirect it multiple times, just one redirect:
`http://example.com` should directly redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

2. Also, an HSTS header should be added.

Question: How can I arrange this in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

To set HSTS you can use this header:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

Then to force HTTPs and WWW use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Comment: Did this help you @mh3982 ?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to the beginning of the `.htaccess` file where example.com is your domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This only addresses one part of the question. This does not deal with the canonical www redirect nor the HSTS header.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to header "includeSubDomains" so redirect can be just http://example.com -> https://www.example.com.
This only have drawback that ALL subdomain need ssl enabled AND forced to use. Only if you planned not to use subdomains or they will have ssl properly configured

---

No, you cannot escape with 2 redirect.

Non www and www is interpreted as different host (domain and subdomain)
To correctly set it, you must first enforce https by HSTS and then you can redirect to proper one version. Example:
-- http://example.com -> https://example.com (HSTS loaded for this domain) -> redirect
-- http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com (HSTS loaded for this domain) -> redirect

Source: https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-canonical-www-redirects